# Solr - ignore dots, dashes, slash, leading zeros

Tags: search, solr, dspace

I want to know if it's possible to accomplish the following results with Apache Solr and how. Which filters do I need to use?

If I search:

```
search      results            
1.000       1000 or 1.000       (ignore dot in numbers)
007         7 or 007            (ignore leading zeros)
wi-fi       wifi or wi-fi       (ignore dash)
123/456     123 456 or 123/456  (ignore slash)
something   some or someone or something   (similar words)
```

And is it possible to do this without a specific field?
Like in a simple search that I don't use a metadata to search for. 
I need that it works in both cases.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most of these behaviors seems like they would be a good match for the [WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterGraphFilter) - you're going to need to define a custom field to get custom behavior. In particular the last point "similar words" needs to be defined concisely - what is a "similar word"? If you're talking about meaning, you're going to have to find a synonym word list that meets your goal, or start looking into Natural Language Processing (NLP).

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh. When I said "similar word" I mean words that starts with the same prefix. In the example that I wrote the prefix would be SOME.

Comment: That would be implemented by an NGramFilter - I recommend having that as a separate field so you can weigh it approriately